# (C++) How to point to a method in a subclass?

Tags: c++, object, methods, subclass

I have a base class `Base`, which has the method `runUserMethod(void * pointer_to_method)`.

```
class Base {
    int runUserMethod(METHTYPE pointer_to_method) {
        // do some stuff before
        int retval = pointer_to_method();
        // do some stuff after
        return retval;
    }
};
```

Now, I want to implement `runUserMethod` in a way that it is able to run any method implemented by a subclass of `Base`, provided that such method follows some standard signature, such as `int <methodname> (void)`

For instance, suppose the user creates the class `UserClass` like:

```
class UserClass : public Base {
    int user_method (void);
};
```

What should `METHTYPE` be, so that I could do the following?

```
Base   * b = new UserClass();
int retval = b->runUserMethod(&UserClass::user_method);
```

Also, would it work? Is there any better way of doing this? Basically, what I'm trying to do is to intercept invocations to subclass method calls, in a more or less transparent way to the user.

Comment: You are aware of that a `void*` and member function pointers need not necessarily be of the same size (and most often are not), that is casting between them will often fail (besides it being mostly UB anyways)?

Comment: just do `UserClass().user_method()`. forget all that complexity of a `runUserMethod` and derived class and whatnot. invoking member functions is trivial.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the `UserClass` and `user_method` are not known beforehand... I use the `runUserMethod` function to intercept calls to subclass method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making *runUserMethod* a template method. Also in order to safely cast *this* from base to derived class you should use dynamic_cast so *Base* class must by polymorphic (by adding virtual destructor for instance):

```
class Base {
public:

    template <class T>
    int runUserMethod( int (T::* pointer_to_method)()) {
        T* p = dynamic_cast<T*> (this);
        if (p == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("cast error");


        // do some stuff before
        int retval = (p->*pointer_to_method)();
        // do some stuff after
        return retval;
    }

    virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

The function usage is the same as in your code sample:

```
Base* b = new UserClass;
int r = b->runUserMethod(&User::user_method);
```

Function arguments and return type can also be made template parameters so that runUserMethod accepts other function signatures:

```
class Base {
public:

    // 0 arguments
    template <class T, class R>
    int runUserMethod( R (T::* pointer_to_method)()) {
        T* p = dynamic_cast<T*> (this);
        if (p == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("cast error");

        // do some stuff before
        R retval = (p->*pointer_to_method)();
        // do some stuff after
        return retval;
    }

    // 1 argument
    template <class T, class R, class ARG1>
    int runUserMethod( R (T::* pointer_to_method)(ARG1), ARG1 arg1) {
        T* p = dynamic_cast<T*> (this);
        if (p == NULL) throw std::runtime_error("cast error");

        // do some stuff before
        R retval = (p->*pointer_to_method)(arg1);
        // do some stuff after
        return retval;
    }

    // 2 arguments
    // [...]

    virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

This way code below will also work:

```
class UserClass : public Base {
public:
     int   user_method1 (void)  {return 0;}
     float user_method2 (void)  {return 0.0f;}
     int   user_method3 (int x) {return 0;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Base* b = new UserClass;
    int   r1 = b->runUserMethod(&UserClass::user_method1);
    float r2 = b->runUserMethod(&UserClass::user_method2);
    int   r3 = b->runUserMethod(&UserClass::user_method3, 2);
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! It is exactly what I was looking for! For completeness, could you extend your answer with template parameter and return types? Also, how safe is this way of doing things, exactly?

Comment: Dynamic cast will protect you against sibling problem described by @Slava. You can have problems with types deduced for template. For instance if `usermethod3` accepts `int&` instead of `int` and you are passing a literal constant then the code will not compile. But those problems can by eliminated with [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)(`remove_reference` in this specific example).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
struct Base
{
    typedef std::function<int()> METHTYPE;

    int runUserMethod(METHTYPE pointer_to_method)
    {
        return pointer_to_method();
    }
};

UserObject b;
auto func_object = std::bind(&UserObject::user_method, std::ref(b));

int retval = b.runUserMethod(func_object);
```

Comment: Beware that this binds to a copy of `b`. You'll usually want `*b` or `std::ref(b)` as the argument to `bind`, in order to bind to `b` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Joachim. However, would it be possible to somehow encapsulate these extra lines of code (with bind, I mean). I want the user to simply run `obj->runUserMethod(SOMETHING)` instead of `obj->SOMETHING()`.

Comment: @EduardoBezerra To call a non-static member function, you need _both_ the object instance and the function. There's no way around it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Definitely, but wouldn't that be exactly the _this_ pointer passed to runUserMethod? (i.e., _this_ == obj)

Comment: @EduardoBezerra Yes it would be, but then you _have_ to use inheritance, and probably virtual methods (or `this` will be the base class object). Using `std::bind` is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your example in more real workable state you would see the issue:

```
int retval       = (this->*methptr)();
```

Leaving aside ugly syntax, problem is you need to pass "this" pointer which has type Base * to method invocation, but you suppose to pass pointer to method of derived class
So you either need to make runUserMethod aware of derived class (probably by template) or typecast pointer to derived method to a pointer to base method with risk to problems:

```
class Derived1 : public Base ...
class Derived2 : public Base ...
Derived2 d2;
d2.runUserMethod( static_cast<METHTYPE>( &Derived1::func ) ); // problem Derived2 * will be passed to Deriived1 method and there is no easy way to detect that
```

So using std::bind would be safer. And you do not have to inherit from Base (I do not know if that good in your case)